# Getting data from ul li div and storing into json

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, console.log, nightwatch.js

I have think about this for last few hours and can't find any solution. So basically I have a list like this

```
<ul class="list"> 
     <li class="user">
         <div class="name">Name</div>
         <div class="surname">Surname</div>
     </li>
     <li class="user odd">
         <div class="name">Name</div>
         <div class="surname">Surname</div>
     </li>
     <li class="user">
         <div class="name">Name</div>
         <div class="surname">Surname</div>
     </li>
     <!--And like so....-->
</ul>
```

And this is how my nightwatch script looks

```
 .elements('css selector','.li',function(result){
    console.log(result.value);
  });
```

the result is [] = empty array

But the main question is what would be the best practice to execute the all the data in ul li div and write console.log like a json file?

Like :

```
{
    "name": "name",
    "surname": "Yaya",
}, 
{
    "name": "name2",
    "surname": "Yaya2",
},
```

Please If any of you can help, give me some handicap for this.

Comment: I have tested it and it seems to work fine. Is your html within the html tag?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! No there is only <!DOCTYPE html> not <html> but I can't figure it out how to execute the data in json format, and why I'm not getting any text data out in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you can do something like the following in pure JS.

```js
var lis = document.querySelectorAll("ul li"),
      i = 0,
  jData = [];
for (var li of lis) {
  var divs = li.getElementsByTagName("div"),
     liObj = {};
  for (var div of divs) liObj[div.className] = div.textContent;
  jData.push(liObj);
}
jData = JSON.stringify(jData);
console.log(jData);
```

```html
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="user">
      <div class="name">Name</div>
      <div class="surname">Surname</div>
    </li>
    <li class="user odd">
      <div class="name">Name</div>
      <div class="surname">Surname</div>
    </li>
    <li class="user">
      <div class="name">Name</div>
      <div class="surname">Surname</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But I need to run this inside the nightwatch.js like in the example previous

Comment: `.execute(function(){
       var lis = document.querySelectorAll("ul li"),
          i = 0,
        jData = [];
        for (var li of lis) {
          var divs = li.getElementsByTagName("div"),
             liObj = {};
          for (var div of divs) liObj[div.className] = div.textContent;
          jData.push(liObj);
        }
        jData = JSON.stringify(jData);
        console.log(jData);
          })`

Comment: @Kyrgios I am not familiar with Nightwatch.j but i am happy to see that you have found a way to implement it.

Comment: Big Thank you Redu!